# Get specific COUNT value with same ID column

Tags: mysql, sql, request

I have this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM classroom 
WHERE capacity > (SELECT COUNT(class_history.*) 
                  FROM classroom 
                  RIGHT JOIN class_history ON classroom.id_class = class_history.id_class 
                  GROUP BY class_history.id_class) 
ORDER BY id_class DESC
```

And I want to get the classroom capacity from counting class_history record, that same with the classroom id, can anyone help me with this query?

So I can get the return like this

```
classroom 1 - capacity  (0/20)
classroom 2 - capacity  (2/20)
classroom 3 - capacity  (9/10)
```

Here the screenshot

Table **classroom**
[image: classroom]

Table **class_history**
[image: class_history]

NOTE : if the capacity is full then it didnt appear , if not full then it will appear no matter if its still 0

Comment: more detailed table structures maybe?

Comment: Also, some sample data, and the result you want to produce from it would be great. Help us help you.

Comment: thanks for your response, here i already put the screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `LEFT JOIN`, it should solve your issue

```
SELECT classroom.id_class, COUNT(class_history.id_class), capacity 
FROM classroom LEFT JOIN class_history
ON classroom.id_class = class_history.id_class
GROUP BY classroom.id_class
HAVING COUNT(class_history.id_class) < capacity
```

Comment: @Khrisna, please let know if it doesn't help ?

Comment: it works thanks .. but im sorry i forget to say, if the capacity is full then it will not appear, and when the capacity is still 0 it will appear. so when its full it didnt appear, if not full it will appear

Comment: wow thats work fine :D, but why the empty classroom didnt show up? can you help me?

Comment: now it should work perfectly, kindly accept if you like the answer

Comment: but why the empty classroom still didnt show? only the classroom that not empty did show

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a sqlfiddle, I guess there is some understanding issue. Please create a sqlfiddle.

Comment: Its not a big issue and would be easily solvable, just provide me with a sqlfiddle

Comment: why in the sql fiddle theres 3 records? but on my website only show 2 records?

Comment: so right now can you please tell me what is the required output as per you from this data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62229/discussion-between-rockse-and-khrisna-gunanasurya).